# Input Image File in VueJs + SlimPHP

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, frameworks, slim

I am new in VueJs, I want to input image file and some text using vuejs for creating new user. So far, I already make the base64 image, but I don't know how to pass this base64 image to the slim code in the server.
Here is my vue code:

Input File

```
<input class="file-input" type="file" name="userPhoto" @change="uploadPhoto">
```

Method :

```
uploadPhoto: function(e){

  var reader = new FileReader()
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0])

  reader.onload = (e) => {
    this.usr.user_photo = e.target.result
  }
}
```

Post :

```
console.log(this.usr);
this.$http.post('MyAPI', this.usr)
  .then(function(response){
  this.$router.push({path: '/'});
}
```

console.log output this object :
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2gEU.png)

and here is my code in slim post request

```
$app->post('/api/user/add', function(Request $request, Response $response){

  //Upload Files
  $directory = $this->get('upload_directory');
  $uploadFiles = $request->getUploadedFiles();

  $uploadedFile = $uploadFiles['userPhoto'];
  if($uploadedFile->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
      $filename = moveUploadedFile($directory,$uploadedFile);
      $response->write('Uploaded '.$filename.'<br/>');
  }

  function moveUploadedFile($directory, UploadedFile $uploadedFile){
      $extension = pathinfo($uploadedFile->getClientFilename());
      $basename = bin2hex(random_bytes(8));
      $filename = sprinf('%s.%0.8s',$basename, $extension);

      $uploadedFile->moveTo($directory.'/'.$filename);

      return $filename;
  }

  $user_id = $request->getParam('user_id');
  $password = $request->getParam('password');
  $name = $request->getParam('name');
  $status = $request->getParam('status');
  $prodi = $request->getParam('prodi');
  $social_link = $request->getParam('social_link');

  $sql = "INSERT INTO user 
          VALUES (:user_id,:password,:name,:status,:prodi,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),'$filename',:social_link)";

    try{
    // Get DB Object
    $db = new db();
    // Connect
    $db = $db->connect();

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':status', $status);
    $stmt->bindParam(':prodi', $prodi);
    $stmt->bindParam(':social_link', $social_link);

    $stmt->execute();

    echo '{"notice" : {"text": "User Added"}}';


    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"Error": {"text": }'.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});
```

I already try using resteasy and copy paste all object inside the "usr", but i got this error :

> 500 Internal Server Error

Can someone tell me how to do this? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax request contains the image data within a json encoded attribute "user_photo" in form of a [Data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

This is not a "classic" file upload, so this code won't work like expected.

`$uploadFiles = $request->getUploadedFiles();`

**Instead** you may try to read the data URI from the json data.

```
$userPhoto = $request->getParam('user_photo');
```

Then try to decode the data URI string and save it as file.

```
$userPhoto = str_replace("\n", "", $userPhoto);
$userPhotoData = substr($userPhoto, strpos($userPhoto, ',') + 1);

// Decode the base64 string
$userPhotoData = base64_decode($userPhotoData);

// Save the file
file_put_contents('filename.jpg', $userPhotoData);
```

Notice: Never use `echo` in Slim. Use the response object instead.

```
$result = [
   'notice' => [
        'text' => 'User Added'
    ]
];

return $response->withJson($result);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Can u give me example about how to save the file ? So far, I only know explode, and base64_decode, after that i dont know what to do anymore.

Comment: Hi, I gave you an example.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your example, i try it in my localhost and it works, but i dont know why, i do the same thing on hosting server, and i got an error "Internal server error", maybe u can help?

Comment: Hard to guess without seeing the error logfile. Maybe you should check the filesystem write permissions and log all errors into a file: https://akrabat.com/logging-errors-in-slim-3/

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help, will check that later